# SASL authentication fails when called from crontab

Tags: ssh, cron, authentication, sasl

When I run mbsync from the command line it works fine.  But if mbsync is run from the crontab, mbsync fails with this error "`Error: SASL(-1): generic failure:`".

My guess is that mbsync's SASL authentication requires an environment variable that cron is not setting, but after much trying I have not been able to spot the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer to my own question.  Cron does not set the environment variable USER.  Thus, one solution is to run mbsync from inside a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
USER="YOURUSERNAME"; export USER
mbsync gmail
```

Comment: You can do this without a separate script by simply having cron invoke something like `env USER="YOURUSERNAME" mbsync gmail` (or you can set `USER` from within your crontab)